# FirePHP not working inside of required files

Tags: php, firephp

My firePHP works fine, except when I use it inside a class, any ideas why?

```
$firephp = FirePHP::getInstance(true);
$firephp->log('I'm logged from firePHP!!');
```

Will work fine if I stick it somewhere in index.php. But if I put it in a required file, it no longer works.

Comment: Are you including the FirePHP core?